# Error : Incompatible argument type

Tags: magento2, module, error, router

I am facing an error while running command di:compile

This is my block file

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
           
        return '/companymodule/index/booking';
    }
}
```

below is the error i am getting. can someone help me to figure things out

```
Company\Module\Block\Booking
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template; File:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your `__counstruct` function

use this one:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

This should resolve the issue

Answer (score 3):

remove the constructor method from your class. You don't need it if the only thing it does is to call the parent constructor.

Comment: Yes it does not require constructor. Good solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

this now this correct way.
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
array $data = []
)
{
parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

thanks